# encoding objects within a JSON request in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, http

Using Swift 2.0, compiling for IOS 9.2, running Xcode 7.2 on El Capitan

I need to convert this JSON data into a data With JSONObject.

```
{
    "path": "/Prime_Numbers.txt",
    "settings": {
      "requested_visibility": "public"
    }
}
```

I'v been using something like this which worked well, until I got node within a node.

```
let nodeA:NSDictionary? = ["path":"/Prime_Numbers.txt"]
**let nodeB:NSDictionary? = ["requested_visibility":"public"]**
**nodeA?.setValue(nodeB, forKey: "settings")**
do {
  let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(nodeA!, options: [])
} catch {
    print("footer")
}
```

So exclude lines with ** and it works, include them and it will crash....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those Dictionaries need to be mutable to avoid the crash

import Foundation

```
let nodeA:NSMutableDictionary? = ["path":"/Prime_Numbers.txt"]
let nodeB:NSMutableDictionary? = ["requested_visibility":"public"]
nodeA?.setValue(nodeB, forKey: "settings")
do {
  let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(nodeA!, options: [])
} catch {
  print("footer")
}
```

Comment: Yes; its been a long day. THANKYOU; I made nodeA a var [stupid question wasn't it] and it works!! How could I miss that!